# Review dropdown menu

Tags: script, review

## About

This userscript/extension replaces the review button with a dropdown that lists all the review queues on the current site and the number of available posts to review. It simply saves the trouble of going to /review and coming back if there's nothing to review. It also adds a quick access to /tools (provided you have 10k). I know it works in Opera and Chrome, but [I was told it works fine in Firefox as well](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1992512#1992512) (no guarantees).

[image: review]

## Installation

**[Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/review-dropdown-for-stack/ljodngmjfoeaaoniljoifimkagdlkofn)**

You can also use [this userscript](https://gist.github.com/3ventic/11192624) (code below as well) in greasemonkey/tampermonkey or download the [Chrome/Opera extension](https://i.3ventic.eu/reviewdropdown.crx) (drag & drop it to extensions, uses pretty much the same code as userscript).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Review dropdown
// @namespace  stackexchange.com
// @version    1.6
// @description  Review link replaced with a dropdown menu allowing you to access 10k tools and see how many posts there are in each review queue, with links to each one.
// @include    http*://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @include    http*://*stackoverflow.com/*
// @include    http*://*superuser.com/*
// @include    http*://*serverfault.com/*
// @include    http*://*mathoverflow.com/*
// @include    http*://*askubuntu.com/*
// @include    http*://stackapps.com/*
// @exclude    http*://chat.stackexchange.com/*
// @exclude    http*://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @exclude    http*://chat.stackoverflow.com/*
// @require    http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js
// @copyright  2014+, 3ventic
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).ready(function () {
    var visible = false;
    var x1 = 0;
    var x2 = 0;
    var y1 = 0;
    var y2 = 0;
    var repstr = $('.topbar-flair .reputation').text().replace(',', '');
    var rep = parseInt(repstr);

    $('.topbar-menu-links > a[title="Review queues - help improve the site"]').replaceWith('<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="userscript-review-dropdown" class="icon-help">review <span class="triangle"></span></a>');
    $('body').append('.userscript-hidden{display:none !important;}\
#userscript-dropdown{z-index:1000;display:block;position:absolute;width:215px;font-family: \'Helvetica Neue\',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;}\
#userscript-dropdown a{display:block;color:#07c;text-decoration:none;font-size:12px;background-color:#fff;border-bottom:1px solid #eee;padding:10px 7px}\
#userscript-dropdown a:hover{background-color:#eee;}\
#userscript-dropdown a:visited{color:#18529a;}\
#userscript-dropdown a span{display:block;color:#111;margin-top:4px}\
.userscript-clicked{color:#000 !important;background-color:#eee !important;}');
    $('body').append('<div id="userscript-disposal" class="userscript-hidden"></div><div id="userscript-dropdown" class="userscript-hidden topbar-dialog"></div>');
    function doStuff() {
        $('#userscript-dropdown').html('');
        if (visible) {
            $('#userscript-dropdown').addClass('userscript-hidden');
            $('#userscript-review-dropdown').removeClass('userscript-clicked');
        }
        else {
            if (rep > 9999) {
                $('#userscript-dropdown').html('<a href="/tools"><strong>Tools</strong><span>10k moderation tools</span></a>');
            }
            $('#userscript-dropdown').html($('#userscript-dropdown').html() + '<a href="/review"><strong>Review</strong><span>Access review queues</span></a>');
            $('#userscript-disposal').load("/review .dashboard-item", function (data) {
                $('#userscript-disposal > .dashboard-item').each(function (index) {
                    if (!$(this).find('.dashboard-description').html().match(/You need at least/i)) {
                        var title = $(this).find('.dashboard-title').text();
                        $('#userscript-dropdown').append('<a href="' + getUrl(title) + '"><strong>' + title + '</strong><span><strong>' + $(this).find('.dashboard-num').text() + '</strong> item(s) to review</span></a>');
                        y2 = y2 + 49;
                    }
                });
            });
            var offset = $('#userscript-review-dropdown').offset();
            y1 = offset.top + 34;
            s = rep > 9999 ? 2 : 1;
            y2 = offset.top + 34 + s * 49;
            x1 = offset.left;
            x2 = offset.left + 215;
            $('#userscript-dropdown').removeClass('userscript-hidden').css('top', y1 + "px").css('left', x1 + "px");
            $('#userscript-review-dropdown').addClass('userscript-clicked');

        }
        visible = !visible;
    }
    $('#userscript-review-dropdown').click(function (e) {
        if (!visible) window.setTimeout(function () { doStuff(); }, 1);
    });
    $('#userscript-review-dropdown').dblclick(function (e) {
        window.location = "/review";
    });
    $(document).click(function (e) {
        if (!(e.pageX > x1 && e.pageX < x2 && e.pageY > y1 && e.pageY < y2) && visible) doStuff();
    });
    function getUrl(que) {
        if (que.match(/Low Quality Posts/)) return "/review/low-quality-posts";
        else if (que.match(/Close Votes/)) return "/review/close";
        else if (que.match(/Reopen Votes/)) return "/review/reopen";
        else if (que.match(/First Posts/)) return "/review/first-posts";
        else if (que.match(/Late Answers/)) return "/review/late-answers";
        else if (que.match(/Suggested Edits/)) return "/review/suggested-edits";
        else if (que.match(/Site Self-Evaluation/)) return "/review/site-eval";
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice userscript, +1! Could you please implement a feature if you double-click on the review link (or click on that link if the dropdown is opened), the review summary (/review) would be opened? Because if I double-click on it now, then the review items just show twice in the list.

Comment: Yes, I meant that. I edited my comment to make that clearer.

Comment: Hmm... it doesn't seem to work for me in Firefox. It still works like before.

Comment: In my previous comment, I actually meant that the dropdown does not show anymore after updating the script. Double-clicking on it shows /review, but clicking once doesn't show anything.

Comment: And it also breaks the "StackExchange" dropdown, that lists the communities.

Comment: @ProgramFOX it works perfectly fine in Chrome, so I'm not sure what the issue could be.

Comment: Strange. I have to go now, but I'll try to find out the problem later. Probably it's a browser-specific issue.

Comment: @3ventic it worked fine for me in FF using the Scriptish addon. But with that no longer supported, I switched back to GreaseMonkey and have exactly the same issues as ProgramFox described: it breaks pretty much all other dropdowns: SE, Inbox, Achievements, even the mod stuff. Console shows a bunch of `TypeError: $(...).<something> is not a function`, if that helps. Funny part: the review dropdown itself works, it just breaks all other dropdowns.

Comment: PS: tracked it down to the `@require` loading jquery. Even if I only leave the comment header and remove all the code, it still breaks – until I remove that `@require`. If I replace that with the same jquery version used by SE pages themselves, dropdowns open again but never complete loading. If I remove it completely, everything works fine – all dropdowns, incl. the script itself. So work-around: remove the `// @require` line. See [here](http://joanpiedra.com/jquery/greasemonkey/) for a possible fix (checking whether JQuery is already loaded and only load it otherwise).

Comment: Is this still being worked on?

Comment: @SirCumference not actively, no

Answer (score 1):

<strike>[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Don't display queues the user doesn't have access to.</strike>

<strike>[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Add the `topbar-dialog` class to `#userscript-dropdown`, so it gets a shadow.</strike>

<strike>[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Emphasize the queue name and number of items in it, as they are more important than "item(s) to review".</strike>

<strike>[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) This site isn't in the list of `@include`s.</strike>